# Proving an identity using a combinatorial proof?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $n\ge k\ge m\ge 0$ be integers. Consider the following formula:
>
> $$\binom{n}k\binom{k}m=\binom{n}m\binom{n-m}{k-m}$$
>
> Give two different proofs. On proof should use the factorial formula for $\binom{n}k$.  The other proof should be combinatorial. Try to develop a question that both sides of the equation answer.

So this question asked us to prove the formula below in two ways, and while I got it for the 1st way [using the factorial formula for $\binom{n}k$], I still don't understand how I can prove this using a combinatorial proof. I'm having trouble constructing a counting argument. Can anyone help me out?